# Restrict registered users from altering their own biographical info

Tags: wordpress

I want to restrict all users from altering their own 'Biographical Info' (only I the admin should be able to edit/update it) in Dashboard->Users->Your Profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with following;

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'disable_profile_edit' );
function disable_profile_edit() {
    remove_menu_page( 'profile.php' );
    remove_submenu_page( 'users.php', 'profile.php' );
    if(IS_PROFILE_PAGE === true && ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

You can put only code part to `functions.php`. If anyone (except the users has role manage_options) tries to access profile page, it will be denied.

**Note:**

Put ;

```
define('IS_PROFILE_PAGE', true);
```

in `profile.php`

Comment: WordPress doesn't offer a 'native capability' for this so a conventional 'Role Editor' won't work.

Comment: @nk-47 see my updated answer for custom function for disable profile edit

Comment: Yes, it is similar to all other user role editor plugins which offer only native 'capabilities' offered by WordPress.

Comment: Ok then, I have added code way of profile edit disable

Comment: This isn't a possible solution because users get "You are not allowed to edit your profile!" page upon login.

Comment: @nk-47 see my updated answer. User will be redirected to home page when go to edit profile

Comment: although it works now but an optimal solution would somehow only disable the bio field while keeping the user profile page and all of its other options accessible!